# Resgatar data-id de um menu

Tags: php, jquery, modal

Como passo o data-id de um link do menu para uma modal? Por exemplo tenho um menu com os link1 - link2 - link3. Ao clicar por exemplo no link2 abra um modal exibindo os valores do link2. Esses valores são resgatados do banco de dados, por isso preciso saber qual o data-id do menu para puxar do banco a informação correspondente a esse data-id.

Comment: Tens de colocar o código que já tens... senão é dificil ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para obter o ID podes usar uma função JavaScript...
Mas não precisa usar necessariamente um atributo Data, já que se tem o atributo ID. Depois podes fazer o que quiser com ele.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.menu > li').on('click', function() {
    var dataId = $(this).attr('id').replace('link-', '');

    console.log(dataId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li id="link-1"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li id="link-2"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li id="link-3"><a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```